# Make keeps building the wrong target with VPATH

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Search-Algorithm.html#Search-Algorithm), regarding **VPATH**:

> After processing the prerequisites, the target may or may not need
> to be rebuilt:
>
> ```
> a.     If the target does _not_ need to be rebuilt, the path to the
>      file found during directory search is used for any
>      prerequisite lists which contain this target.  In short, if
>      'make' doesn't need to rebuild the target then you use the
>      path found via directory search.
>
>
> b.     If the target _does_ need to be rebuilt (is out-of-date), the
>      pathname found during directory search is _thrown away_, and
>      the target is rebuilt using the file name specified in the
>      makefile.  In short, if 'make' must rebuild, then the target
>      is rebuilt locally, not in the directory found via directory
>      search.
> ```

Illustrating the above, with the following makefile - which is basically the same situation as section **`b.`** above - where the *vpath-ized* target turns outs to be *out-of-date*, we write the Makefile, as:

```
$(shell rm -rf all D)
$(shell mkdir D)
$(shell touch D/all)

VPATH = D

all: phony
    echo '$@'

.SILENT: D/all

.PHONY: phony
```

Running, I get:

```
echo 'D/all'
D/all
```

Now, given that above quote that:

> "if the target *does* need to be rebuilt (is out-of-date), the pathname found during directory search is *thrown away*, and the target is rebuilt using the file name specified in the makefile"

Why, then does Make build `D/all`, as evident by the output of the command, and not the *original* (before it was *vpath-ized*) target?

Comment: Why are you using make? Surely summat like gradle or SCONS would be better

Answer (score 1):

Simply `make` builds `D/all` because you have specified `.SECONDARY: D/all` which prevents `make` from "automatically deleting", i.e. throwing away, the pathname of `D/all`.

If you remove (or comment out) `.SECONDARY: D/all` and run `make --debug` on

```
$(shell rm -rf all D)
$(shell mkdir D)
$(shell touch D/all)

VPATH = D

all: phony
    echo '$@'

.PHONY: phony
```

the output should be similar to

> Reading makefiles...
>   Updating goal targets....
>     File 'phony' does not exist.
>    Must remake target 'phony'.
>    Successfully remade target file 'phony'.
>   Prerequisite 'phony' of target 'all' does not exist.
>   Must remake target 'all'.
>    **Ignoring VPATH name 'D/all'.**
>   **echo 'all'**
>   **all**
>   **Successfully remade target file 'all'.**

Here we can clearly see `make` now throws away the pathname of `D/all` and rebuilds `all` locally as per the documentation you've quoted.

---

`.SECONDARY` is documented in [Special Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) in the GNU Make Documentation.